# how to compile the latest rdiff-backup in debian?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, debian

The problem here is that in my ubuntu desktop pc, the repositories contain the latest rdiff (1.2.8), but in my debian server, the repositories contain v1.2.5.
I get an error that the versions are different, therefore I need to compile v1.2.8 in debian myself and I have really no idea how to do that.

Can anyone help me?

http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [rdiff-backup package version / debian release](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=rdiff-backup&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). You can see that 1.2.8-6 is available since squeeze.

If your server is running lenny, maybe it would be a good idea to upgrade to squeeze (see [this blog entry](http://www.go2linux.org/how-to-upgrade-from-debian-lenny-to-squeeze) or look on Google). If you can't upgrade, try to compile rdiff-backup from source and manage the resulting binaries within /usr/local.